# Prove that $B^{c} \subseteq A^{c} \Rightarrow A \subseteq B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

How do I prove that $B^{c} \subseteq A^{c} \Rightarrow A \subseteq B$?

I tried:

Take $x \in B^{c}$. We want to prove $\forall x \in A, x \in B$

By definition of the subset, $\forall x \in B^{c}, x \in A^{c}$

Then I got stuck not knowing where to go...

Comment: Show your attempts and I'll show my solution.

Comment: It is a common mistake for beginners to start a proof with the assumption. But that does not work here. You want to show $A\subseteq B$ after all, and for that (by definition of the subset inclusion) you have to show that for $x\in A$ we have $x\in B$. So a proof should start with "Let $x\in A$ .... ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to show that $A\subseteq B$ under the assumption that $B^c\subseteq A^c$.

To do so we have to show that for $x\in A$ we have $x\in B$.

So let $x\in A$. Then $x\notin A^c$. Since $B^c\subseteq A^c$ this means $x\notin B^c$. So $x\in B$, and we are done.

Alternative:

Let $x\in A$. Suppose $x\notin B$. Then $x\in B^c$, and therefore $x\in A^c$, which is a contradiction, as $x\in A$ and $x\in A^c$ can not hold.

Comment: ooooh so in these types of proofs, the LHS is only there in order to provide "facts", and by taking $x \in A$, we are using these "facts" in order to prove $x \in B$

Comment: @h4ppyturt1e Yes. Basically every proof is written under certain assumptions. "If .... holds, we can proof .... ". So your exercise reads "Under the assumption that $B^c\subseteq A^c$, we can proof that $A\subseteq B$".

Comment: Or literally $B^c\subseteq A^c$ implies that $A\subseteq B$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the contrapositive can be used, modus tollens.

Modus tollens tells us that if $p \implies q$, then $\neg q \implies \neg p$, where $\neg$ indicates logical negation.

$x\in B^c \implies x \in A^c$ by hypothesis.

Here, $p=x \in B^c$, so $\neg p= x \in B$

We also have $q=x\in A^c$, so $\neg q=x \in A$.

Modus tollens gives us $\neg q \implies \neg p$, thus we conclude $x \in A \implies x\in B$. The conclusion follows by definition of a subset.

Alternative approach:
$p \implies q$ is logically equivalent to the disjuction $q \vee  \neg p$.

So we have as our hypothesis  $x \in A^c \vee x \in B$. The veracity of the disjunction implies at least one of the two statements is true. If we have that $x\in A$, then the first half of the disjunction is false, so the second half must be true, thus $x \in B$.